# Edit Cell value of a datagridview after set datasource

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` and set it's `Datasource` to a table from a dataset (data.xsd)

here is my question:

Is there any way to edit the value of the cells and then show them?

for example I have a currency field and for some reasons I have to store it as int in database but when I want to show it I need to change the format to currency again.

is there any way to do that?

Comment: it looks like You need to use the DataGridView.CellFormatting Event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TymurGubayev thanks it helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CellFormatting` event of `dataGridView` you can do this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.ColumnIndex == 4)
            {
                e.Value = e.Value + "I Just changed";
            }
        }
```